# Torsion-free ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $I=(x^2,xy,y^2,p(z)x-q(z)y)$, where $K$ is a field and $p$ and $q$ relatively prime polynomials.

> How could I show that the ideal $(x,y)/I$ in the ring $K[x,y,z]/I$ is torsion-free as $K[z]$-module?

If $X=\operatorname{Spec} (K[x,y,z]/I)$ conclude that $X$ is primary with $X_{\text{red}}\simeq \operatorname{Spec} (K[x,y,z]/(x,y))$ and has multiplicity two.

Answer (score 1):

The question reduces to when $a(z)x+b(z)y\in I$ and it is not hard to show that this happens if and only if $a(z)=p(z)u(z)$ and $b(z)=-q(z)u(z)$ for some $u\in K[z]$.